# Negative number of rows in data.table after incorrect use of set

Tags: r, data.table

I've come across something a bit wierd, especially because the code may give different outputs each time it's run. In a nutshell I was incorrectly using `set` to set a value in a row bigger than the last one but instead of doing nothing `set` created a negative length `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)

dt<-data.table(id=1:5, var=rnorm(5)) # normal example

set(dt, 6L, 1L, 3L) # doesn't set anything as expected.
dt
#
# now my real data, after I found the error in my code (incorrect row number in set)
#
dt1 <- data.table(ID = "29502509", FY = 2012, VAR = 61067.5442975645, 
                      startDate = structure(15062L, class = c("IDate", "Date")), 
                      endDate = structure(15429L, class = c("IDate", "Date")), 
                      start = "1750", end = "2404",
                      date = structure(15461L,class = c("IDate", "Date")),
                      DESCR = "JOB", NOTE = "NEW")

set(dt1, 12L, 3L, 62385.6516144086)
str(dt1)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ ID       : chr "29502509"
 $ FY       : num 2012
 $ VAR      : num 61068
 $ startDate: IDate, format: "2011-03-29"
 $ endDate  :
Error in do.call(str, c(list(object = obj), aList, list(...)), quote = TRUE) : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed
> sapply(dt1, length)
        ID         FY        VAR  startDate    endDate      start        end       date 
         1          1          1          1 -637110831          1          1          1 
     DESCR       NOTE 
         1          1 
> dput(dt1)
structure(list(ID = "29502509", FY = 2012, VAR = 61067.5442975645, 
    startDate = structure(15062L, class = c("IDate", "Date")), 
    endDate = structure(, class = c("IDate", "Date")), start = "1750", # HERE
    end = "2404", date = structure(15461L, class = c("IDate", 
    "Date")), DESCR = "JOB", NOTE = "NEW"), .Names = c("ID", 
"FY", "VAR", "startDate", "endDate", "start", "end", "date", 
"DESCR", "NOTE"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000130788>)
```

As I said above you may need to run some times the entire code to see that, from the creation of the data.table `dt1 <- data.table(...` to `set(dt1,...`, because I noticed that if it doesn't happen the first time it won't ever happen *unless* I re-run `dt1 <- data.table(...` . Any idea?

EDIT:

To be specific, when I say different result I mean that sometimes it does nothing (as expected) but most of the times it creates a negative length column **always** `the Date`, and sometimes it creates an entire `data.table` with negative rows. **Plus**, in the last two cases (single column or entire `data.table`) the negative length is always `-637110831`

Comment: @Vivi thanks very much for corrections, I was very tired. I posted the question yesterday night after a 15 hour session :-(

Comment: I've linked your question on `data.table` forum: http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/datatable-help/2013-June/001840.html

Comment: @Arun you are always more than useful, even when you don't have the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like memory corruption due to writing beyond the memory allocated for the column.

This calls to `assign` in `assign.c`.  From version 1.8.8, assign.c:434:

```
434             default :
435                 for (r=0; r<targetlen; r++)
436                     memcpy((char *)DATAPTR(targetcol) + (INTEGER(rows)[r]-1)*size, 
437                            (char *)DATAPTR(RHS) + (r%vlen) * size,
438                            size);
```

This code is reached (which should not be the case).  At this point:

```
(gdb) p INTEGER(rows)[0]
$21 = 12
(gdb) p size
$23 = 8
```

Comment: According to this answer http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/datatable-help/2013-June/001842.html on the `data.table` forum it seems you are right

Comment: @Michele The debugger rarely lies.