# Merge error : negative length vectors are not allowed

Tags: r, merge

I tried to merge two data.frames, and they are like below:

```
   GVKEY YEAR coperol     delta     vega firm_related_wealth
1 001045 1992       1  38.88885 17.86943            2998.816
2 001045 1993       1  33.57905 19.19287            2286.418
3 001045 1994       1  48.54719 16.85830            3924.053
4 001045 1995       1 111.46762 38.71565            8550.903
5 001045 1996       1 218.89279 45.59413           17834.921
6 001045 1997       1 415.61461 51.45863           34279.515
```

AND

```
   GVKEY YEAR fracdirafter fracdirafterindep twfracdirafter
1 001004 1996         1.00              0.70    1.000000000
2 001004 1997         0.00              0.00    0.000000000
3 001004 1998         0.00              0.00    0.000000000
4 001004 1999         0.00              0.00    0.000000000
5 001004 2000         0.00              0.00    0.000000000
6 001004 2001         0.25              0.25    0.009645437
```

They both have 1,048,575 rows. My code is `merge(a,b,by=c("GVKEY","YEAR"))`, I kept receiving error message "`negative length vectors are not allowed`". I also tried the data.table way, but got error message saying that my results would exceed 2^31 rows. Apparently, the merged data will not be so big, so I am not sure how to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you have duplicates for the `by` columns in both datasets?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842263/memory-limits-in-data-table-negative-length-vectors-are-not-allowed It seems to be a memory problem.
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-January/425051.html

Comment: try `nrow(duplicated(a[,c("GVKEY","YEAR")])` and `nrow(duplicated(b[,c("GVKEY","YEAR")])` to count number of rows with duplicate keys

Comment: @akrun You are right, one of the data has duplicates for the by column

Answer (score 23):

You are getting this error because the `data.frame` / `data.table` created by the join has more than `2^31 - 1` rows (2,147,483,647).

Due to the way vectors are constructed internally by R, the maximum length of any vector is `2^31 - 1` elements (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5234293/2341679). Since a `data.frame` / `data.table` is really a `list()` of vectors, this limit also applies to the number of rows.

As other people have commented and answered, unfortunately you won't be able to construct this `data.table`, and its likely there are that many rows because of duplicate matches between your two `data.tables` (these may or may not be intentional on your part).

The good news is, if the duplicate matches are *not* errors, and you still want to perform the join, there is a way around it: you just need to do whatever computation you wanted to do on the resulting `data.table` in the same call as the join using the `data.table[]` operator, `e.g.`:

```
dt_left[dt_right, on = .(GVKEY, YEAR), 
        j = .(sum(firm_related_wealth), mean(fracdirafterindep),
        by = .EACHI]
```

If you're not familiar with the `data.table` syntax, you can perform calculations on columns within a `data.table` as shown above using the `j` argument. When performing a join using this syntax, computation in `j` is performed on the `data.table` created by the join.

The key here is the `by = .EACHI` argument. This breaks the join (and subsequent computation in `j`) down into smaller components: one `data.table` for each row in `dt_right` and its matches in `dt_left`, avoiding the problem of creating a `data.table` with > `2^31 - 1` rows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how `merge` is implemented, but there seems to be a big difference when you try to merge by one column or by two, as you can see in the following simulation:

```
> df1<-data.frame(a=1:200000,b=2*(1:200000),c=3*(1:200000))
> df2<-data.frame(a=-df1$a,b=-df1$b,d=4*(1:200000))
> ss<-sample(200000,10000)
> df2[ss,1:2]<-df1[ss,1:2]
> system.time(df3<-merge(x=df1,y=df2,by=c('a','b')))
user  system elapsed 
1.25    0.00    1.25
> system.time(df4<-merge(x=df1,y=df2,by='a'))
user  system elapsed 
0.06    0.00    0.06
```

Looking at the system memory the two-column merge used a lot more memory as well. There's probably a cartesian product in there somewhere and I guess this is what's causing your error.

What you could do is to create a new column concatenating GVKEY and YEAR for each data.frame and merge by that column.

```
a$newKey<-paste(a$GVKEY,a$YEAR,sep='_')
b$newKey<-paste(b$GVKEY,b$YEAR,sep='_')
c<-merge(a,b,by='newKey')
```

You would need to clean up the columns in the result, since GVKEY and YEAR would both appear twice, but at least the merge should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while performing a task in r similar to vlookup present in MS Excel. This error is there because your key column is not good enough to map data from one table to another table. Better remove zeros or make a column unique as explained by @Assaf Wool. Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

Something I just realize that caused the error in my case is that there are many NAs in the matched column. After removing the missing values, my problem was solved.