# Rcpp R vector size limit (negative length vectors are not allowed)

Tags: r, rcpp

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/48676389/3846213 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/5234293/3846213 R vectors are limited 2^31 - 1 items. However, I've been able to trigger the "negative length vectors are not allowed" error (which is supposed to be a sign of trying to allocate an overly large vector) at half that number via Rcpp. This all comes from my trying to debug an Rcpp-based R package (https://github.com/tpq/propr/issues/13).

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction("
IntegerVector test(int size) {
    int veclen = size * (size - 1) / 2;
    IntegerVector vec(veclen);
    return vec;
}
")

vec <- test(47000)
Error in test(47000) : negative length vectors are not allowed
```

47000^2 / 2 is nearly half of 2^31.
I've got no such problems in pure R, that is `vec <- 1:(47000*(47000-1)/2)` runs fine, so there should be something special with Rcpp.

Comment: No, @duckmayr is right. I can replicate your problem. But it is not just an overflow. We have to keep looking.

Comment: @Jan it actually is an overflow, but just due to order of operations; see my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is multiplication overflow. When you do

```cpp
size * (size - 1) / 2
```

order of operations bites you, because

```cpp
size * (size - 1)
```

can overflow even if the overall expression doesn't.
We can see this by adding a printing statement:

```cpp
IntegerVector test(int size) {
    int veclen = size * (size - 1) / 2;
    Rcpp::Rcout << veclen << std::endl;
    IntegerVector vec(veclen);
    return vec;
}
```

```r
vec <- test(47000)
# -1043007148
```

So, we can fix it by changing up how we do that operation:

```cpp
IntegerVector test(int size) {
    int veclen = (size / 2) * (size - 1);
    Rcpp::Rcout << veclen << std::endl;
    IntegerVector vec(veclen);
    return vec;
}
```

which gives no issue

```r
vec <- test(47000)
# 1104476500
str(vec)
# int [1:1104476500] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

#### Update: The problem with odd numbers

[Eli Korvigo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3846213/eli-korvigo) brings up an excellent point in the comments about integer division behavior with odd numbers. To illustrate consider calling the function with the even number 4 and the odd number 5

```r
even <- 4
odd  <- 5

even * (even - 1) / 2
# [1] 6
odd  * (odd  - 1) / 2
# [1] 10
```

It should create vectors of length 6 and 10 respectively.
But, what happens?

```r
test(4)
# 6
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
test(5)
# 8
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Oh no!
`5 / 2` in integer division is 2, not 2.5, so this does not quite do what we want in the odd case.
However, luckily we can easily address this with a simple flow control:

```cpp
IntegerVector test2(int size) {
    int veclen;
    if ( size % 2 == 0 ) {
        veclen = (size / 2) * (size - 1);
    } else {
        veclen = size * ((size - 1) / 2);
    }
    Rcpp::Rcout << veclen << std::endl;
    IntegerVector vec(veclen);
    return vec;
}
```

We can see this handles the odd and even cases both just fine:

```r
test2(4)
# 6
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
test2(5)
# 10
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks for reaffirming the doubts I had about that arithmetic expression.

Comment: Unfortunately, the reordering gets you into another sort of trouble: integer division. `veclen = size * (size - 1) / 2;` evaluates the same for odd and even integers. However, `(size / 2) * (size - 1)` behaves differently for odd and even numbers.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Excellent point! I'm sorry I overlooked this initially. I've addressed it in an update to the answer.